# Getting the name of an event from CustomEvent

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a CustomEvent parameter on a function and I'd like retreive the name of the event, i.e. the string it was constructed with (`new CustomEvent('foo')`)

For ref's sake https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

```
    public addEvent(iChannel: number, oEvent: CustomEvent)
    {
        if (App.isDebugging)
        {
            console.log(CustomEvent+' emitted '+CustomEvent.typeArg+' on channel '+iChannel);   
            console.log(CustomEvent);   
        }
        this.aEventChannels[iChannel].dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }

//what lib.dom.d.ts says about this
declare var CustomEvent: {
    prototype: CustomEvent;
    new<T>(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: CustomEventInit<T>): 
CustomEvent<T>;
};
```

I've tried `type` and `typeArg`. Both return the error:

```
tsc --build src-webui/ts
src-webui/ts/App.ts(162,53): error TS2339: Property 'typeArg' does not exist on type '{ new <T>(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: CustomEventInit<T> | undefined): CustomEvent<T>; prototype: CustomEvent<any>; }'.`
```

I'm getting back into the swing of TS so I'm sure this is quite simple and the right syntax just isn't "clicking" with me.

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks!

PS: This targeting the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the `.type` property of the `CustomEvent` class, rather than the `oEvent` object that gets passed to the function. Try using this instead:

```
public addEvent(iChannel: number, oEvent: CustomEvent) {
    if (App.isDebugging) {
        console.log('Emitted ' + oEvent.type + ' on channel ' + iChannel);   
        console.log(oEvent);   
    }
    this.aEventChannels[iChannel].dispatchEvent(oEvent);
}
```

Comment: Well, this is what an 18 hour day will do you. Even programmers need sleep!